# Filter data from json with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, django-rest-framework

I need to filter students by class and then push that to `HTML` pattern.

Here's the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/GG9EYmPlIyD4ZM0ehaq6?p=preview

.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ClassController">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

.js:

```
var app;

app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('ClassController', [
  '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.students = [];
    return $http.get('data.json').then(function(result) {
      return angular.forEach(result.data, function(item) {
        return $scope.students.push(item);
      });
    });
  }
]);
```

you can find `.json` file on the link

Answer (score 0):

Here is your controller:

```
var app;

app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('ClassController', [
  '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var someFilter = 'taple';
    $scope.students = [];
    return $http.get('data.json').then(function(result) {
      $scope.students = result.data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.classroom.school.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(someFilter) > -1;
      })
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks!
But I have many classes, so how can I associate particular class with list of students?